Timeline after git push --force
After push --force my commit dates are not the same.
What's going on? My remote repo when I type .patch still shows the original date, but in the github history it says joao committed yesterday
git show -s --format=%ci 0bf6721
output: 2024-10-09 14:38:20 -0300
git log 0bf6721
output: Date:   Wed Sep 18 17:10:54 2024 -0300

The behavior you're seeing results from Git maintaining two different kinds of dates for every commit: the committer date and the author date.
The first date of the modifications was this one. If the commit is updated, rebased, or otherwise changed (unless updated explicitly using a command option), this date remains unchanged.
This is the date on which the commit was last applied or modified (for example, by a force push, rebase, or amend). When the commit is modified or rewritten, this is the date that is updated.
It's very possible that you changed the committer date when you force-pushed (git push --force). You may see the date of the push or the latest modification to the commit by using the git show -s --format=%ci  command, which by default displays the committer date.
That being said, the difference you see is because the author date—which was originally attached to the commit—is still shown in the.patch view on GitHub.
git show -s --format=%ai <commit>

git show -s --format=%ai 0bf6721

This will show you the author date, which should align with what you see in the .patch view on GitHub.
git log --pretty=fuller <commit>

This will help you comprehend the discrepancy by displaying the "AuthorDate" and the "CommitDate" to you.
Recall that manipulating a commit's history through actions like force pushes, rebases, and amends can cause these kinds of differences between the different timestamps linked to a commit.

How do I have only the original commits because this messed up my github?
